# How to include apostrophe (') in MySql Update statement?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have a update query
Eg: `'update table1 set text="Sample text'"'`
How to include apostrophe(') in the query without running into Parse error 1064

Comment: Doubling up the single quote is usually the way to do it, e.g. `update table1 set text = 'Sample text''';`

Answer (score 1):

you have to escape the special characters with a back slash "\"

`\'`